# How to navigate keyboard keys between widgets in gridview on Flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I want to build a TV application with Flutter but I can't navigate between widgets with remote commander buttons.

```
BaseTheme(
  title: "Title",
  actions: null,
  child: GestureDetector(
    behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
    onTap: () {
      FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
    },
    child: GridView.count(
      childAspectRatio: (itemWidth / itemHeight),
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      crossAxisCount: 2,
      children: (_list == null) ? <Widget>[Text("")] : _list,
    ),
  ),
)
```